# FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS Causes content to go below navigation bars

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Using the following code causes my layout to extend below the navigation bars. Id just like to change the status bar color without messing up the layout.

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            getWindow().setStatusBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(R.color.statusbar_color));
            //TRANSPARENT FOR TESTING
            getWindow().setNavigationBarColor(this.getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
        }
```

I feel like I'm missing something...

[image]

Comment: Post your layout. I can't seem to re-create this.

Comment: Everything is just match_parent, nothing crazy. As you can see I'm using Sliding Menu, which I think might be causing the issue. There's got to be some function to override whatever's happening though.

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                                |  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting this flag

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
```

before `super.onCreate(savedInstance)`

And after super, anytime in the activity you can set the Status bar color.

Comment: Check if you have set FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION flag

Comment: @ShanXeeshi Try using `android:fitSystemWindows="true"` to the `View` in the layout which is going below the Navigation Bar

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu/issues/680#issuecomment-66604727 for solution

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "attachToActivity":

```
SlidingMenu slidingMenu = new SlidingMenu(getApplicationContext());
slidingMenu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT, false);
```

And extend SherlockFragmentActivity (or FragmentActivity) instead of SlidingFragmentActivity.

But this way your ActionBar will not slide of course....